# Create a hyperlink that will expire after one click

Tags: java, spring-boot, session-cookies

I am creating an hyperlink that will be send to user mail(gmail in my case). I want to expire the link after user once clicked in it(I don't want the user to click more than once).Once user clicked on the link it will trigger subsequent mail to manager. Here I also want similar functionality.

Note: link has some encrypted data too.It should remain intact.

Comment: If its a link, isnt it Javascript related? Once clicked, disable or you require something more complex?

Comment: It's not Javascript related. Link is like https://test.qa.xyz.com?approve=encrytedstring . This link is created in spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.Instead of relying on session.I am using last update value in DB to check the life of hyperlink.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).